# How to test GCM notifications without app?

Tags: android, testing, amazon-web-services

I am currently implementing a push functionality using `Amazon SNS` in my backend. Now, I would like to write tests for the backend and make somehow sure that the published notifications get delivered to the endpoint (GCM mobile device).

Is there a way to get a mock `registrationID` from the Google dev console and check an inbox if any notifications actually arrived? All without ever building an app?

Comment: Same problem here. Unbelievable, that Google supports DRY_RUN but offers no endpoint to test?

Answer (score 7):

GCM works also with Chrome.

And there's a sample Chrome App available here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/gcm-notifications - it's available in Chrome's app store and it lets you obtain the `registration_id` for your `sender_id` and then see your messages as Chrome notifications. All using a simple popup window, without writing a single line of code.

Comment: Awesome, and with ChromeDriver this can be fully automated in a headless cli environment!