# test firebase cloud messaging without app

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a backend for a Android and iOS App and we decided to use the "new" Firebase Service by Google.
I now want to test if my backend service works as expected but we have no working apps yet. Is there any option to test FCM in Browser or any other tool (like the GCM Plugin for Chrome, which is not compatible with Firebase)

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Yes, It is possible to test FCM push notifications without using android App.refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34981410

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could you the FCM quick start app available on Github.
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging

If you configure the app for your project you can check that your backend is working successfully.